# Azure App Service Environment Connection to Site to Site VPN

Tags: azure, networking

I have just started using Azure. I created a vnet, subnet, gateway, and site to site vpn. Created a VM and can hit anything on the on premise network. This seems to be working fine in both directions. Created an app service environment initially with a public VIP. This created a subdomain. Added this subdomain to the firewall rules. I can ping vm in original subdomain but can't hit anything on premise. Not sure what I am missing. I am currently redeploying App Service Environment with internal VIP to see if this helps. Any advise on what may be the issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The ILB ASE simply changes the HTTP/S, publishing endpoint to be on a private IP in the Azure VNet rather than on an external IP.  It doesn't change the access an ASE has.  Set your ASE up with an external IP or an ILB based on how you want to use it.  Ping has issues in a VNet as ICMP is blocked by a number of things.  There are two nice ways I use to check access to an endpoint.  If you have an ASE just make an app in the ASE then go to the console for the app and use tcpping.  That is a utility that lets you hit a TCP host:port combination to see if you can reach it.  If you don't have an ASE then there are some utilities you can yank down onto a VM to do the same thing.  You can even use things like telnet to see if you can hit a port.  Long story short, use something that does TCP to check connectivity.  Unless you set up a Network Security Group to block access or botched the routes when setting up the VPN, your apps in the ASE should have access to resources on premises.